# filter out rows of a spark dataframe based on a count condition of specific value in a column [spark.sql syntax in pyspark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following spark dataframe:

```py
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled = pd.DataFrame( 
                           {'id' : ['001', '001', '001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '002'],
                            'OuterSensorConnected':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
                            'OuterHumidity':[31.784826, 32.784826, 33.784826, 43.784826, 23.784826, 54.784826, 31.784826, 31.784826],
                            'EnergyConsumption': [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70],
                            'DaysDeploymentDate': [10, 20, 21, 31, 41, 11, 19, 57],
                            'label': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
                           )
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled = spark.createDataFrame(datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled )

# printSchema of the datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled (spark df):

"root
 |-- IMEI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OuterSensorConnected: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- OuterHumidity: float (nullable = true)
 |-- EnergyConsumption: float (nullable = true)
 |-- DaysDeploymentDate: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = false)"
```

As you can see for the first id *'001'* I have 5 rows and for the second id *'002'* I have 3 rows. What I want is to filter out the rows connected to the ids that their positive label ('1') is less than 2 in total. So, since for the first id *'001'* the number of positive labels is equal to 3 (three rows with positive label 1 in total) and for the second id *'002'* only 1 row with positive label, I want all the rows related to the id *'002'* to be filtered out. So my final df would look like:

```py
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled_filtered = pd.DataFrame( 
                           {'id' : ['001', '001', '001', '001', '001'],
                            'OuterSensorConnected':[0, 0, 0, 1], 
                            'OuterHumidity':[31.784826, 32.784826, 33.784826, 43.784826, 23.784826],
                            'EnergyConsumption': [70, 70, 70, 70, 70],
                            'DaysDeploymentDate': [10, 20, 21, 31, 41],
                            'label': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]}
                           )
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled_filtered = spark.createDataFrame(datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled_filtered)
```

How is this achievable with a spark.sql() query?, like

```py
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled_filtered.createOrReplaceTempView("df_filtered")

spark_dataset_filtered=spark.sql("""SELECT *, count(label) as counted_label FROM df_filtered GROUP BY id HAVING counted_label >=2""") #how to only count the positive values here?
```

Comment: `count(label) >= 2` ?

Comment: @chlebek Just posted a sample code of what I want to do, I did not tested if what written inside the spark.sql query is correct since I am not sure how to correctly write it. That is why I need some help :)

Comment: so te correct query should be `SELECT id, count(label) as counted_label 
FROM df_filtered 
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(label) >=2`  then you can join other columns using id, you can't select them all using * without putting them in group by

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a window:

```
datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled.createOrReplaceTempView("df_filtered")

spark.sql("""select * from (select *, sum(label) over (partition by id) as Sum_l
                      from df_filtered) where Sum_l >= 2""").drop("Sum_l").show()
```

---

```
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
| id|OuterSensorConnected|OuterHumidity|EnergyConsumption|DaysDeploymentDate|label|
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
|001|                   0|    31.784826|               70|                10|    0|
|001|                   0|    32.784826|               70|                20|    0|
|001|                   0|    33.784826|               70|                21|    1|
|001|                   1|    43.784826|               70|                31|    1|
|001|                   0|    23.784826|               70|                41|    1|
+---+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```